# Alternative L'Hôpital Rule for Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let U an open connected in $\mathbb{C}$ which contains the complementary of a disk with center 0, $f$ and $g$ non constant differentiable functions in U, verifying that exists

$$\lim_{z\to \infty } f(z)=\lim_{z\to \infty } g(z)=0.$$

Prove that the following limits exists and

$$\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}.$$

I have already prove the following theorem:

Let U an open connected in $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ and $g$ non constant differentiable functions in U, $z_0\in U$ and suppose that $f(z_0)=g(z_0)=0$. Prove that the following limits exists and

$$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}.$$

I don't know how can I relate this result with the first.

Comment: Did you try to apply your result to $F(z)=f(1/z)$, $G(z) = g(1/z)$?

Comment: No. If I tried this is inmediate, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you know about removable singularities.

Comment: I don't know about removable singularities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(w) = f(1/w)$ and $G(w) = g(1/w)$ are defined and holomorphic in a *punctured* disk
$D = \{ 0 < \lvert w \rvert < r \}$ for some $r > 0$, and satisfy
$$
 \lim_{w\to 0 } F(w)=\lim_{w\to 0} G(w)=0.
$$

It follows from [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem)
that both $F$ and $G$ can be extended to holomorphic functions
on $\{ \lvert w \rvert < r \}$ by defining $F(0) = G(0) = 0$.

Now you can apply the known result to $F$, $G$ and $z_0 = 0$:
$$
\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} =
 \lim_{w\to 0} \frac{F(w)}{G(w)} =
\lim_{w\to 0} \frac{F'(w)}{G'(w)} =
\lim_{w\to 0} \frac{-f'(1/w)/w^2}{-g'(1/w)/w^2} =
\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)} \quad .
$$